# Error cannot load such file -- user_agent/browsers/playstation (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

When in run rails s or rails c 
in a project ruby v2.1.4 and rails 3.2.13

> /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- user_agent/browsers/playstation (LoadError)
>       from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`block in require'
>       from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
>       from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`require'
>       from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/useragent-0.16.0/lib/user_agent/browsers.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
>       from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`require'
>       from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
>       from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in`load_dependency'
>       from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
>       from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/useragent-0.16.0/lib/user_agent.rb:2:in`' 
>       from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
>       from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`block in require'
>       from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
>       from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`require'
>       from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/useragent-0.16.0/lib/useragent.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
>       from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`require'
>       from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
>       from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in`load_dependency'
>       from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
>       from /home/kop/rails/howtobuyafranchise/lib/franchise_core/lib/franchise.rb:11:in`'
>       from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
>       from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in`block (2 levels) in require'
>       from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
>       from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in`block in require'
>       from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
>       from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in`require'
>       from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
>       from /home/kop/rails/howtobuyafranchise/config/application.rb:7:in`'
>       from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `require'
>       from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in`'
>       from script/rails:6:in `require'
>       from script/rails:6:in`'

i dont know fix this error
pls help me

Comment: The playstation library isn't properly loaded in you project. Could you past in your gem file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the file path is wrong,
Instead of: `user_agent/browsers/playstation`
change it to:

```
useragent/browsers/playstation
```

Since I don't know what is in your Gemfile, one of the assumptions i'm making about this error is that you have not included `gem 'useragent', '~> 0.14.0'` in your Gemfile and then ran `bundle install`

Comment: tks :D
ur save my day